# Setting color assignment order with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, color-ramp

I have a shapefile feature class with the following attribute table:

[image]

I set the shapefile symbology using these lines:

`lyr.symbology.valueField = "GRIDCODE"
lyr.symbology.addAllValues()`

What i get is this:

[image]

The color range is not in ascending order. It is starting at "10".

When I click on the color range ("Farbverlauf"), it changes to an ascending order, starting at "2". However, I have too many shapefiles to do this for each single one.

How can I adjust this color assignment in ArcPy?

**EDIT**

I'm using this workaround now: 
[How To: Add leading zeros to values in a field in an attribute table](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013035)

Example code: fill each row of field "GRIDCODE" of layer "lyr" with "002"

`with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr, "GRIDCODE") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = (str(2).zfill(3))
         cursor.updateRow(row)`

Comment: Understandable if you want to do everything programatically, but you could also use a template layer to apply the symbology:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm

Comment: I am. I put it inside a loop where the template layer values are changed, its symbology updated and then applied on the respective shape file with every iteration. The template layer values are always >= the shape file values. The symbology in the image is from one of the shape files.
The application of the template layer symbology is working, only the color order is messed up.